# Citep and Citet not working in VEHITS Conference Template

Tags: natbib

In VEHITS conference's template (https://www.scitepress.org/documents/SCITEPRESS_Conference_Latex.zip), I have tried to use `\citep` and `\citet` commands and have gotten the error: "Undefined Control Sequence."

I tried to add `\usepackage{natbib}` before and after `\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}`, but the result did not change. I started to get a different error: "Command \bibhang already defined."

Any solution?

Comment: Try replacing `\usepackage{apalike}` in the preamble with `\usepackage{natbib}`.

Comment: This should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The sample file has `\usepackage{apalike}`, a very old package and doesn't provide `\citep`, `\citet`. Therefore you can replace
`\usepackage{apalike}`
with
`\usepackage{natbib}`.